# How to get URL parameters inside apk if the apk is hosted on my server and not on app store?

Tags: php, android, firebase, google-analytics

I want to track UTM Parameters, number of download and installs in google analytics or firebase. The apk file is hosted on my server

**Example**: https://www.companyname.com/. The parameter I want to track is UTM parameters.

> URL Sample (Adwords or Adserver):
>   https://www.companyname.com/?utm_source=fb&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=aclpromo&utm_term=paid&utm_content=fbpost

I want when the user clicks and download the apk file, apk file know the URL from which this was downloaded after installation so that I can fire an event to save the UTM information in database or firebase.

I hope I am able to explain my requirement. Appreciate your responses in advance.

Comment: Please use curl function

Comment: _“I want when user clicks and download the apk file, apk file know the URL from which this was downloaded”_ - sounds very much impossible … you might as well try and ask your dinner vegetables, which supermarket they were bought from - pointless, they don’t have any access to that info.

Comment: Noop its different.